# Getting deployment unsuccessful in power tools for tableau deployment tool when adding Pre and post deployment script

Tags: deployment, tableau-api

If I follow the deployment plan steps in power tools for tableau deployment by Interworks and does not include pre and post deployment script, the deployment process runs successfully.
But if I write a simple help command(just an eg) in pre/post  deployment custom script , Help command executes but still deployment fails and I get this O/P:

---

Power Tools for Tableau Deployment by InterWorks, Inc.
   Version 1.25.5

### Build 1.25.5

```
               Started : 6/8/2017 7:01:01 PM
                  Plan : -
                  File : -
         Deployment ID : 20da7047-75e8-4bc4-8c12-b2d0f809e32c

                Source : http://guptamo@tableauqa.blackstone.com:80/t/Compliance
           Destination : http://guptamo@localhost:8000/

              Projects : All projects

             Workbooks : New Security Holdings [Project: Security Holdings]

Published Data Sources : No selections

 Reset Dashboard Focus : Yes
```

Overwrite Newer Workbooks : Yes
    Enable Extract Refresh : Yes
              Auto Archive : No

---

Executing pre-deployment scripts.
Starting: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\git\Script\tempscript.cmd"
in directory: C:\git\Script
------- Stdout -------

C:\git\Script>help
For more information on a specific command, type HELP command-name
ASSOC          Displays or modifies file extension associations.
ATTRIB         Displays or changes file attributes.
.
..other help commands

For more information on tools see the command-line reference in the online help.
------- End Stdout -------
Process duration was 00:00:00.3809387
**Process exited with code 1**
[ERR]: Deployment failed.
Deployment complete.

---

```
            Workbooks   Published Data Sources    Bytes   Transfer Duration
   Source :         0                        0   0.00 B            00:00:00
```

Destination :         0                        0   0.00 B            00:00:00
 Auto Archive :         0                        0   0.00 B            00:00:00

```
    Ended : 6/8/2017 7:01:01 PM
 Duration : 00:00:00.4350000
Exit Code : 0
```

[image: Screenshot of script]

Anyone who knows what is wrong with the command or power tools for tableau deployment executes some different commands?

Answer (score 1):

[InterWorks](https://www.interworks.com/)' [Power Tools for Tableau Deployment](https://powertoolsfortableau.com/tools/deployment/) tool executes those "custom scripts" as Windows batch file scripts. The script's exit code is checked to determine whether it ended with an error. By convention, any non-zero exit code is considered an error code and will mark the deployment as a failed.

In your example, the `help` command in a Windows batch file returns an exit code of 1.

You could use this as your script to make the build succeed:

`help
exit /B 0`

Or use any other script that returns an exit code of `0`.